# Flutter: Cache Manager for plain values?

Tags: flutter

assuming an app executes some calculations which run so long, that the result should becached. Furthermore, it doesn't necessarily know if the result is going to be used or not (or maybe it's used 3 times, but never after that); but it is save to delete the cached value after 5 days. 
Is there some library which can accomplish that? It should basically be the same as the package flutter_cache_manager but for plain values (like Strings or numbers) instead of files from the internet.

SharedPreferences would be an option; but here it would require a decent amount of work to clean the expired values.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I started to work on a package for this: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences_cache

Might be helpful for others as well!